# How to uninstall CDT and reinstall?

Tags: eosio.cdt

On Ubuntu 16 / Windows with Linux Module.

For reinstalling EOSIO, I'm just removing my `eosio_1.5.0-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb`

Then:

```
wget https://github.com/eosio/eos/releases/download/v1.5.0/eosio_1.5.0-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio_1.5.0-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb
```

And when I call `node -v`, I get 1.5; however, how should I go about removing/reinstalling the CDT?  [The docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit) say to do: `sudo apt remove eosio.cdt` which I'm calling in the path that has: `contracts  eosio_1.5.0-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb  eosio.cdt  nodeos.log  notes.txt`

However, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package eosio.cdt
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'eosio.cdt'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'eosio.cdt'
```

Calling within the `eosio.cdt` folder yields the same response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uninstalling current **eosio.cdt** go to **usr/local** there you find **eosio.cdt** folder just delete that folder and again install your required version.